# Dividing specific cell in data column

Tags: r, division

I am trying to divide the first observation for each specific ID with 0.25.

How can I do this?

E.g. I want to divide the first observation for ID 24 with 0.25, so that the value (currently 10) will change to (10/0.25) = 40

The code should do the same for all IDs which have 'Obs = 1', so e.g. the first observation of ID "25" should be (5/0.25) = 20.

An example of my data could be as follows:

```
Obs ID  Value
1   24  10
2   24  4
3   24  2
4   24  3
5   24  5
6   24  4
7   24  2
8   24  1
1   25  5
2   25  6
3   25  2
4   25  4
```

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the `Value` with 0.25 where `Obs = 1`.

```
inds <- df$Obs == 1
df$Value[inds] <- df$Value[inds]/0.25
df

#   Obs ID Value
#1    1 24    40
#2    2 24     4
#3    3 24     2
#4    4 24     3
#5    5 24     5
#6    6 24     4
#7    7 24     2
#8    8 24     1
#9    1 25    20
#10   2 25     6
#11   3 25     2
#12   4 25     4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Obs = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L), ID = c(24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L), Value = c(10L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak!
I guess 'Inds' is a fictive dataframe you are refering to right?

Comment: Actually `df` is the dataframe name.

Comment: Of course.. So what excatly is the [inds] refering to? Shouldn't I be able to overwrite the existing data within an existing column? In this case the 'value' column

Comment: Yes, my answer is overwriting the existing column `Value`. Don't get confused with `inds`, it is a temporary variable I created. My answer can be written as `df$Value[df$Obs == 1] <- df$Value[df$Obs == 1]/0.25`. To avoid writing the same condition twice (`df$Obs == 1`) I created a temporary variable `inds` to store the logical values.

Comment: I tried this solution, however the cell does not seem to change its value?

crsp.comp3$xsgaq [crsp.comp3$Observation == 1] <-  
crsp.comp3$xsgaq [crsp.comp3$Observation == 1] /0.25

Comment: Do you get any warning or error messages after running the code? Do you have `NA` values in `Observation` column? I included the data in a reproducible format which I am using and it works on that data. Can you copy that and check if my answer works on that data for you? If it works for you on the sample data in my answer but doesn't work on your original data then can you share your actual data in similar reproducible format using `dput`? You can edit your post with output of `dput(head(crsp.comp3), 10)`.

Comment: Hi Ronak, It works now. I just had to run the entire script again, as I ran the code in an already existing data frame. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using `ifelse` which is easy to comprehend

- baseR way

```
df$Value <- ifelse(df$Obs == 1, df$Value/ 0.25, df$Value)
```

or `dplyr` way

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Value = ifelse(Obs == 1, Value/0.25, Value))

   Obs ID Value
1    1 24    40
2    2 24     4
3    3 24     2
4    4 24     3
5    5 24     5
6    6 24     4
7    7 24     2
8    8 24     1
9    1 25    20
10   2 25     6
11   3 25     2
12   4 25     4
```